# adding textfield,label above the uitableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

How to design a tableview similar contact application in iphone.........

Comment: Can you be more specific, there are different kinds of tableviews used in the contacts application?

Comment: adding new contact view's table view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want the delegate method:

`- (UIView)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderAtSection:(NSInteger)section;`

construct and return a UIView in that method.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely they use UITableView with grouped style and custom views for table header and footer. (see tableFooterView and tableHeaderView properties)